# Modifying PayPal IPN listener to handle multiple queries when payment is complete

Tags: php, mysql, sql, paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm having trouble modifying my PayPal IPN listener due to my lack of knowledge of PHP.

After payment has completed my IPN listener inserts details of the transacation into the table 'payments', however I now need the script to also update another table named 'Members' so I can easily tell who has paid.

This is the SQL I have come up with:

```
"UPDATE `Members` SET paid='TRUE' WHERE id='".$data['custom']."'
```

I'm using the IPN variable 'custom' to send the users ID through from the original payment form.

I have tried implementing mysqli_multi_query into the script but with no success. I'm really stuck on this one, if someone could point me in the right direction that would be awesome.

Here is my PHP:

```
function check_txnid($tnxid){
    global $link;
    return true;
    $valid_txnid = true;
    //get result set
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `payments` WHERE txnid = '$tnxid'", $link);       
    if($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
        $valid_txnid = false;
    }
    return $valid_txnid;
}

function check_price($price, $id){
    $valid_price = false;
    //you could use the below to check whether the correct price has been paid for the product

    /* 
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT amount FROM `products` WHERE id = '$id'");       
    if (mysql_numrows($sql) != 0) {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
            $num = (float)$row['amount'];
            if($num == $price){
                $valid_price = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return $valid_price;
    */
    return true;
}

function updatePayments($data){ 
    global $link;
    if(is_array($data)){                
        $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `payments` (txnid, payment_amount, payment_status, itemid, createdtime) VALUES (
                '".$data['txn_id']."' ,
                '".$data['payment_amount']."' ,
                '".$data['payment_status']."' ,
                '".$data['item_number']."' ,
                '".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."' 
                )", $link);

    return mysql_insert_id($link);
    }
}

//Database Connection
$link = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
mysql_select_db($db_name);

// Check if paypal request or response
if (!isset($_POST["txn_id"]) && !isset($_POST["txn_type"])){

    // Firstly Append paypal account to querystring
    $querystring .= "?business=".urlencode($paypal_email)."&";  

    // Append amount& currency (£) to quersytring so it cannot be edited in html

    //The item name and amount can be brought in dynamically by querying the $_POST['item_number'] variable.
    $querystring .= "item_name=".urlencode($item_name)."&";
    $querystring .= "amount=".urlencode($item_amount)."&";

    //loop for posted values and append to querystring
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
        $querystring .= "$key=$value&";
    }

    // Append paypal return addresses
    $querystring .= "return=".urlencode(stripslashes($return_url))."&";
    $querystring .= "cancel_return=".urlencode(stripslashes($cancel_url))."&";
    $querystring .= "notify_url=".urlencode($notify_url);

    // Append querystring with custom field
    //$querystring .= "&custom=".USERID;

    // Redirect to paypal IPN
    header('location:https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr'.$querystring);
    exit();

}else{

    // Response from Paypal

    // read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
    $req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
        $value = preg_replace('/(.*[^%^0^D])(%0A)(.*)/i','${1}%0D%0A${3}',$value);// IPN fix
        $req .= "&$key=$value";
}

    // assign posted variables to local variables
    $data['item_name']          = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['item_name']);
    $data['item_number']        = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['item_number']);
    $data['payment_status']     = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['payment_status']);
    $data['payment_amount']     = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['mc_gross']);
    $data['payment_currency']   = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['mc_currency']);
    $data['txn_id']             = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['txn_id']);
    $data['receiver_email']     = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['receiver_email']);
    $data['payer_email']        = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['payer_email']);
    $data['custom']             = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['custom']);

    // post back to PayPal system to validate
    $header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";

    $fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30); 

    if (!$fp) {
        // HTTP ERROR
    } else {    

        fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
        while (!feof($fp)) {
            $res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
            if (strcmp($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {

                // Used for debugging
                //@mail("you@youremail.com", "PAYPAL DEBUGGING", "Verified Response<br />data = <pre>".print_r($post, true)."</pre>");

                // Validate payment (Check unique txnid & correct price)
                $valid_txnid = check_txnid($data['txn_id']);
                $valid_price = check_price($data['payment_amount'], $data['item_number']);
                // PAYMENT VALIDATED & VERIFIED!
                if($valid_txnid && $valid_price){               
                    $orderid = updatePayments($data);       
                    if($orderid){                   
                        // Payment has been made & successfully inserted into the Database                              
                    }else{                              
                    // Error inserting into DB
                    // E-mail admin or alert user
                    }
                }else{                  
                    // Payment made but data has been changed
                    // E-mail admin or alert user
                }                       

            }else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {

                // PAYMENT INVALID & INVESTIGATE MANUALY! 
                // E-mail admin or alert user

                // Used for debugging
                //@mail("you@youremail.com", "PAYPAL DEBUGGING", "Invalid Response<br />data = <pre>".print_r($post, true)."</pre>");
            }       
        }       
    fclose ($fp);
    }   
}
?>
```

Comment: exactly what problem are you having? any errors?

Answer (score 0):

Just make two queries

```
function updatePayments($data){ 
    global $link;
    if(is_array($data)){                
        $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `payments` (txnid, payment_amount, payment_status, itemid, createdtime) VALUES (
                '".$data['txn_id']."' ,
                '".$data['payment_amount']."' ,
                '".$data['payment_status']."' ,
                '".$data['item_number']."' ,
                '".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."' 
                )", $link);
         mysql_query("UPDATE `Members` SET paid='TRUE' WHERE id='".$data['custom'], $link);
    return mysql_insert_id($link);
    }
}
```

Comment: ok so make sure `.$data['custom']` is not empty and use this `paid='1'` instead of `paid='TRUE'`. What about debbuging your code by yourself? Add `echo mysql_error()` after update query